# How to correctly call function from .h header file?

Tags: c

I have no experience with C or C++. Could somebody help me and write short example, how i should use function from SDK?

There is .header file with lot of possibilities, but i need only one at the moment:

```
typedef enum
{
    ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_UP,
    ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_DOWN
} ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL_TYPE;

// Set LCD backlight brightness
ASR_EXPORT bool ASR_API AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL_TYPE Ctrl);
```

In SDK documentation I found:

Set LCD brightness.

```
bool AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL Ctrl)
```

Parameters
Ctrl
[in] The value can be either

- `ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_UP` LCD brightness up.
- `ESCORE_LCDBTCTL_DOWN` LCD brightness down.

Return Value

true Indicates success.

false Indicates failure.

Comment: Which function are you trying to call?

Comment: `bool status = AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBRCTL_UP);`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The following prototype besides providing information during link and compile-time, also provides direction to the programmer on how to call it without ever having to see its implementation:

```
bool AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBR_CONTROL Ctrl)
  |                                     |__indicates argument type to be passed         
  |________________________________________indicates type of return value
```

So a calling example could be:

```
while(dimButtonPressed)//stay in loop as long as dim button is pressed
{
    if(!AsrLibSetLcdBacklight(ESCORE_LCDBTCTL_DOWN))
    {
        //handle error
    }
    Sleep(0.10);
}
```

Assumes there is a handler function that sets `dimButtonPressed` to `true` when it detects button is pressed.  As an alternate, the `swtich - case` statement might also be a good construct to use.

*...how i should use function from SDK?*

Note, because this is an API call, compile-time can be accomplished using the `.c` along with only the API  `.h` file and corresponding [static library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-vs-dynamic-libraries/)   Program *visibility* to the actual `.dll` (or `shared library` if using Linux.) is needed during execution.

More information on [linking with static libs using GCC environment](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)